# Displaying currency symbol in NumericUpDown

Tags: vb.net, currency, numericupdown

I am trying to display a "£" in a NumericUpDown in VB.NET. So far, I have created a custom control called CurrencyUpDown and in the designer code, changed the inherits line so that it inherits NumericUpDown properties. I know I have to use an override for this control, but I'm not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the UpdateEditText method:

```
Public Class CurrencyUpDown
  Inherits NumericUpDown

  Protected Overrides Sub UpdateEditText()
    Me.Text = String.Format("{0:C}", Me.Value)
  End Sub

End Class
```